# Jenkins, Block or fail a job if any of its upstream jobs failed or unstable

Tags: jenkins

What is the best approach to block or fail a Jenkins downstream job if any of its upstream jobs have failed or are unstable?

At the moment i have got the "Block build when upstream project is building" option ticked and that's working fine as my downstream job is waiting all the upstream job to finish building. However i don't want to build the job if any of the upstream failed or is unstable.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you make a job dependent on prior jobs, the trigger is visible both in the triggering job at the bottom and the triggered job at the top.   If you look at the triggering job at the bottom, there are options to decide if the job is triggered only on success or regardless of the outcome of the job.

Make sure the setting in the `Build Other Projects`setting is set to `Trigger only if build succeeds`

Comment: Thanks gaige for your answer, I have configured exactly as you mentioned and a job will only trigger other jobs only if it succeeded. The issue is when for example.
ProjectA is configured to "Build after other projects are built" ProjectB,ProjectC,ProjectD.
Now , if ProjectC fails it won obviously trigger a build for A but the other ones will when they pass. 
So I want a way to stop/fail ProjectA if any of ProjectB/C/D fails.
Thanks again

Comment: Ah, it wasn't clear that the preceding jobs were being run in parallel, not serially.  Check out the join plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin) which allows you to specify a job to run after a set of other jobs are run and the Build Flow Plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) for more complex parallel build and join operations.

Comment: you suggestion is probably the righ way to solve this issue. However in my case it might be a nightmare to workout the build flow for the 70 projects i have, specially when they have a spagetti like inter-dependency on each other. 
I am trying to do something with maven to go around the problem.

Comment: If it's really spaghetti-like you might want to seriously look at the Build Flow Plugin.  It's amazingly flexible and uses it's own DSL (domain-specific language) to describe interdependencies.